# Can not write to sqlite db in packaged air

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, air

I can write to db when running in IDE(FB), while after packaging a air, the app wont write to sqlite db, Why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your database file located after install. If it is the install folder (ex. c:\program files\MyApp) then this is wrong. You have no rights to write in there.  ????

Answer (score 0):

The likely cause is that your installed Air application can't resolve the path to your sqlite file.

What I normally do is to use one of the static public properties of the File class to resolve my sqlite file from eg.

```
databaseConnection = new SQLConnection();
databaseConnection.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, onOpen);
databaseConnection.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, onError);               
databaseConnection.openAsync(File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath('mydb.sqlite'));
```

The key bit here is the **File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath('mydb.sqlite')** line, in this instance AIR will look for a file called mydb.sqlite in the directory that the application is installed into - in your development environment this would be the same as the bin-debug folder (or whatever folder you are compiling to).

Hope that helps, if not if you can post the code you are using , and what error you are getting I will try and help you further.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that your DB file resides in the application directory, which is read only.

From Flex 3.5 Language Reference:

> File.applicationDirectory—the read-only directory where the application is installed (along with any installed assets)

If this is the case, a possible but not only easy fix would be to just use File.applicationStorageDirectory.

Hope this helps.

N.